# Doing simultaneous things in a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to run this bash script:

```
source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
gnome-terminal --tab -e "conda activate env_num_1 && jupyter lab"
conda activate env_num_2
cd some_path 
gnome-terminal --tab -e "sleep 5 && firefox myurl" #
bash "command that starts web server" #It takes a few moment to boot up hence the sleep function
```

For whatever reason gnome-terminal are opening the tabs but neither are executing the commands it has been given. What can I do to fix this?

EDIT: Tried suggestion below (gnome-terminal --tab -- sleep 5 && firefox myurl) in just the terminal, I get

Failed to execute child process “conda activate machine-learning-env & jupyter lab”: Failed to execve: No such file or directory

EDIT 2: Kept on fiddling with it, this gives roughly what I want.

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

conda activate env1 && jupyter lab &
(conda activate env2
cd mydir
bash webui.sh & (sleep 10 && firefox myurl))
```

but it seems to do everything in one terminal. I would like to close one program and keep the other at my discretion.But I guess there must be another way?

Comment: the `-e` option is tricky, maybe using `--` instead of -e helps? like: `gnome-terminal --tab -- sleep 5 && firefox myurl`

Comment: Sadly not working :(

Comment: Your error message does not match what you say you are running.  Try removing the quotes around the command.  The firefox suggestion example works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, your want to do something like that:

```bash
gnome-terminal --tab -- sh -c "conda activate env_num_1 && jupyter lab"
```

@see warning in `man gnome-terminal` for `--command, -e=COMMAND` option

Add a `read` command for debugging:

```bash
gnome-terminal --tab -- sh -c "conda activate env_num_1 && jupyter lab; read -p \"press enter key\""
```

Comment: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_core'". Hm. Jupyter lab is installed and if I just type it manually in console it does work. So I guess somehow the new shell is not seeing it.